# Backup Failed, need help not failing

Tags: 12.04, backup, deja-dup, aws

Backup (Deja Dup) failed to do an initial backup to my Amazon S3, and despite my best Googling efforts, I could not find a solution : (

Here's the error message:

```
BackendException: Error uploading s3+http://deja-dup-auto-akiaiksyiqi3buaaz26a/My-Archive/duplicity-full.20130805T143807Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a System76. The folder I'm trying to backup to in S3 is set to store as Amazon Glacier Storage.

Any help would rock!

Update: better debugging info:

```
DUPLICITY: . Failed to create bucket (attempt #1) 'deja-dup-auto-axxxxxxxxxxxa' failed (reason: S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
DUPLICITY: . <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
DUPLICITY: . <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>47 00 54 0a 0a 0a 4d 6f 6e 00 20 30 35 20 00 75 67 20 32 30 31 00 00 35 00 32 34 3a 31 32 20 47 4d 00 0a 2f 64 65 6a 61 2d 64 75 70 2d 61 75 74 6f 2d 61 6b 69 00 6b 73 79 69 71 69 33 62 75 61 00 7a 32 36 61 2f</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>8000000000003</RequestId><HostId>Uxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRF</HostId><SignatureProvided>yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>GET
```

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't really any information in that error message. Is there an extended version you can show us?

Comment: That's all that backup spit out. Is there some way I can access logs?

Comment: Close deja and then in a terminal run: `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup` and it should be a lot more explicit with its logging.

Comment: And now my terminal looks like the matrix.... be back in a few minutes.

Comment: Okay, that finished, it seems the key is wrong. But is that a hickup with http or did I put in the wrong access keys for aws

Comment: Yeah I'd be leaning toward this being the keys at fault.

Comment: Let's try some new keys...

Comment: Seems like it's working now. Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 5):

Could it be that the credentials you've provided to Déjà Dup does not allow it to create a bucket in the top level of your S3 account?

How about this: Create a bucket in S3, then a user who can read and write there, and ensure that Déjà Dup will use the bucket and user you've created.

1. After creating your bucket, visit https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#users
2. Create a new user (ensure that "generate an access key for this user" is checked)
3. Save the credentials. You're going to input these into Déjà Dup later.
4. Click on the new user and choose "attach user policy."
5. Under the Select Policy Template window, select "Amazon S3 Full Access." Click "Apply Policy" in the confirmation window.
6. Do `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.
7. Do `dconf-editor`.
8. In dconf editor, navigate to org > gnome > deja-dup > s3.
9. Under the Key named "bucket," change the Value to the name of the S3 bucket you have already created.
10. Run deja-dup / "Backup" again, and ensure that the backup location is correct. Input the new credentials. Run the backup and test a single small folder first.

Comment: Thanks, Forest! I'll give this a try when I get a moment.

Comment: How'd that go @Costa?